# How to set an header with Axios module and vuejs in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to define an "Accept-Language" header for my SPA in [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) (with [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/)).

Here's what I tried but it doesn't work. I specify that I use the [axios module for nuxt](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/).

I created a plugin as [explained in the documentation](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend). I included the plugin in nuxt.config.js.

I tried to use `setHeader` as explained [here](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers#setheader-name-value-scopes-common), but it doesn't work.

```
export default function ({ store, $axios, redirect }) {
  $axios.setBaseURL(process.env.BASE_URL);

  if (process.server) {
    return
  }

  $axios.onRequest(config => {
    const baseUrl = $axios.defaults.baseURL;

    const locale = store.getters['lang/locale'];

    if (locale) {
      $axios.setHeader('Accept-Language', locale)
    }
  });
}
```

But this code doesn't work. However, when I make `console.log`, I see them so it is taken into account.

Answer (score 3):

Use [$axios.interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) instead of $axios.onRequest

```
export default function({store, $axios, redirect}) {
        $axios.setBaseURL(process.env.BASE_URL);
        if (process.server) {
            return
        }
        $axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {

            const baseUrl = $axios.defaults.baseURL;

            const locale = store.getters['lang/locale'];

            if (locale) {
                $axios.setHeader('Accept-Language', locale)
            }
            return config;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

how are you making the request? If you want to use the helpers (setHeader, setToken, ...) provided by @nuxtjs/axios, you then must always use the request helpers provided by it, that are simply the lowercase http method names prefixed with a $

Instead of `$axios.get( ... )` use `$axios.$get( ... )` and so on for put, post, delete...

You can also try setting headers this way:

```js
$axios.onRequest(config => {
    const baseUrl = $axios.defaults.baseURL;

    const locale = store.getters['lang/locale'];

    if (locale) {
        config.headers.common['Accept-Language'] = locale;
    }
});
```